# Using nested rendering in React

Tags: reactjs

In my `return`, I call a function called `renderRuns` as follows.

```
return (
    <div>
        {renderRuns()}
    </div>
)
```

My `renderRuns()` looks like

```
const renderRuns = (type) => {
    const renderNested = (run) => {
        return (
            [1,2,3].map((item, idx) => {
                return <div>{run + item}</div>
            })

        )
    }

    [1,2,3].map((run, idx) => {
          renderNested(run)
    })
}
```

Basically trying to render a nested component, but not getting any output without an error.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `return [1,2,3].map((...` ? And one inside - `return renderNested(run)`

Comment: can you share the error?

Comment: @GokuAfrica not getting any error, but it just doesn't render anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `renderRuns` function does not return anything, that's why nothing appears. Simply add a `return` keyword.

```
const renderRuns = (type) => {
    const renderNested = (run) => {
        return (
            [1,2,3].map((item, idx) => {
                return <div>{run + item}</div>
            })

        )
    }

    return [1,2,3].map((run, idx) => renderNested(run));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to follow the same pattern as you specified?

What do you think of this solution?

```js
const renderRuns = (type) => {
  return (
   [1,2,3].map((item, idx) => {
     return <div>{run + item}</div>
   })
}
```

Comment: I actually modified my code in my question to simplify my question. I just wanted to render items in a nested way.

Answer (score 0):

you're pretty close, try this

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const renderRuns = type => {
    const renderNested = run => {
      return [1, 2, 3].map((item, idx) => {
        return <div>{run + item}</div>;
      });
    };
    // return each call to renderedNested
    return [1, 2, 3].map((run, idx) => renderNested(run));
  };
  return <div>{renderRuns()}</div>;
}
```

the above works but it may be more useful to return a component instead of calling a function like this:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  // receive props around from outterComponent
  const InnerComponent = ({ run }) => {
    return [1, 2, 3].map(item => <div>{run + item}</div>);
  };


  const OutterComponent = props => {
    // have can pass props around
    return [1, 2, 3].map(run => <InnerComponent {...{ run, ...props }} />);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {/* easily pass props and stay with a known rendering pattern */}
      <OutterComponent />
    </div>
  );
}
```